# Human vs Dinosaur conflict in post apocalyptic world

Tags: post-apocalypse, fauna, dinosaurs, conflict

500 years post apocalypse, human society is based on small settlements surrounded by electric fences. This is because, during this time dinosaurs have returned to roam the earth.

These dinosaurs are animals that hunt and breed. They are NOT monsters with an agenda.

I am having difficulty in generating conflict/situations which are unique for this setting. I came up with the following for now:

1. An earthquake causes a stampede of triceratops that head straight for the fence and tear it down, exposing the settlement to other predators and scavengers.
2. A carnivore kills a human in self-defense. After this, it gets a taste for human flesh and goes on a man-eating spree

   What other interesting conflicts are possible in this setting?

Comment: sounds like a  fan of the Cadillacs and Dinosaurs comic.

Comment: Be carefull to not ask questions that are too broad or open ended if you can.

Comment: Why not a Pit Masters like cooking drama?

Comment: Well, it's good to know that those humans have a reliable and yummy meat supply.

Comment: To finish @MarvintheParanoidAndroid's sentence "e take the [tour] and when you have some free time read-up in the [help] about how we work."

Comment: Besides the content of my (now-deleted) typoed comment (thanks @Anewnormal), I also feel that it is worth noting that Worldbuilding.SE's  [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) technically discourages "idea farm" questions like yours. Instead, perhaps can you  ask about the viability of different possible outcomes for your scenario? (If you do so, please note that having multiple questions in one "question" is also discouraged.) While I personally will not vote to close, I do think that it's probably going to happen.

Comment: Please: The Earth. Capital letter. It is only lowercase when speaking of dirt.

Answer (score 4):

**Take cues from The Walking Dead.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Walking_Dead_(TV_series)

> The series features a large ensemble cast as survivors of a zombie
>   apocalypse, trying to stay alive under near-constant threat of attacks
>   from the mindless zombies, colloquially known as "walkers". However,
>   with the fall of humanity, these survivors also face conflict from
>   other living survivors who have formed groups and communities with
>   their own sets of laws and morals, often leading to hostile conflict
>   between the human communities.

The zombies are just a force to be reckoned with.  Like bad weather, but with better makeup.  Nearly all of the drama has to do with interpersonal interactions.

But maybe you have no patience for weeping and holding and scheming and heartwrenchedness.  If so we are kindred spirits.   Let me refer you to a formative influence of my own:
  **The Valley of the Dinosaurs!**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valley_of_the_Dinosaurs

> Science professor John Butler and his family... are on a rafting trip
>   along the Amazon River when their raft hits a rock and capsizes. They
>   are swept through a cavern and caught in a whirlpool; upon
>   resurfacing, they find themselves in a mysterious realm where humans
>   coexist with various prehistoric creatures, including dinosaurs. The
>   Butlers meet and befriend a clan of Neanderthals...

You will need to order the disc but you will not be disappointed.  The formative influence was the creative approach all parties took to their problems.   There was not much interpersonal drama although some issues with other cave people groups, for example one group worshipped a chalk-painted stegosaurus that someone had released and people were upset.   More natural hazards - a T Rex with an agenda, sabertooth wandered in and has to be caught alive and brought back where it belongs (because it keeps worse things away!).  Army ants.  Volcanoes.  Mass dino migrations.  Your people could keep busy with crisis of the week and at the same time trying to restore old tech, searching the ruins, taming dinos to ride etc.

Answer (score 2):

Why do animals attack?

Humanity found a resource in their ecosystem.
Coal mines to restart the industry or a Valley with ample prey. Both are in the hunting grounds of these toothy fellas.

Check reptiles which favour a certain breeding ground, like alligators and tortoises.
The humans settled down before breeding season and now they are fending off waves after waves of Dinos bent on laying down their eggs.

Humans won't move, the Dinos are pressed by their biological clock to do it and do it HERE!

No easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas

ankilosaurs are covered in armor and spikes and may never notice an electric fence.

Pterosaurs can fly over an electric fence.

Fences are great until you need something outside the fence, like wood, ore, clay, water, ect.

Smaller carnivores may be able to get around an electric fence,  specifically if there is livestock to act as a lure.

Your settlment is on a migration route and herd of thousands accidentally push member's in to the fence, cause damage to the fence and stampedes.

A large dino dies up wind settlement it stinks and it is attracting predators and scavengers.

The settlement is dead center for a parasaurolophus lekking ground, and the constant noise of their calls is deafening.

Supersaurus or some other large dino become hyper aggressive during the mating season and keep attacking everything.

you can't build an electric fence across a river and dinos keep getting in by walking down the river.

Small herbivores can get around the fence and keep eating the crops.

Aquatic predators keep attacking the fishing ships.

drunk teenagers keep harassing dinos into attacking the fence.

Poachers